# Can I combine two shear-stresses acting on one plane?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses

For example, I have an axial force and a torsion force applied on a rock socket installed in bedrock. If I am considering the side friction between socket and rock as a resistance, the socket surface will have two shear stress generated, one in axial direction, and the other in radial direction. If I want to design this, what is the maximum I should use?

Can I combine the two stresses by triangle rule, or simply adding them up, or only take the larger one?

Here is a conceptual sketch:

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with Von Mise's stress criterion? Essentially you need to look at the combined stress state when these are acting simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you, ShadowMan. Simply, do you have a simple answer on this. If there are two shear stresses acting on one plane, in perpendicular direction, what is the correct way to combine them?

Comment: Duplicated on Physics see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477678/207455

Comment: @Christian777 if you can provide your attempt at looking at the combination so far I can assist you from there. But I think as it stands you have a pretty broad question and you haven't shown any work. You should review Von Mises, attempt to identify which shears you have in his equation. Basically It isn't clear to me what the stresses are on your problem, in your OP it seems different than in your comment. Best to draw them up and name them so you can use Von Mises.

Comment: Hi ShadowMan, Von Mises is a very theoretical formation, I don't know exactly how to use it. My attempt is that i want to know when I have two shear stresses acting on one plane in perpendicular direction, what is the real stresses on my surface now? Is it the resultant of the two stresses, or sum of the two, or the greater of the two will control, or it is in a way but not a simply like this.  I am just not sure what is the final stress level in reality. I initially thought using the resultant, just like two force in two direction, or any vector. But stress seems to be scalar.

Comment: i am not sure you understand my question or not. I think it's a basic concept of how to treat tau(xy) and tau(xz) combined.

Comment: Von Misses is the magnitude of the resultant stress vector. It IS the way you should combine all stresses in order to determine stress magnitude to compare with yield.

Comment: In your OP you say radial and axial stress, now your saying the stresses are in plane? Draw a picture label your shears then it will be possible to answer your question.

Comment: can we vector sum stresses??? this is my concern

Comment: If they are in the same plane, I usually vector sum them. Assuming the cross section is axially symmetrical (a circle) then the shear stress area is the same regardless of vector direction.

Comment: But in your OP you say that you have an axial shear stress due to friction, and a torsion caused radial stress. They are not in the same plane, and they should be combined using VonMises or some other interaction equation.

Comment: it is a little confusing, the axial here i mean a shear stress on the surface, but acting in upward, as I said, considering the side friction, so both stresses are 'shear stresses' (see OP) I will try to draw it...

Comment: I understand, you have a skin friction. But wont this also accompany an axial normal stress? Try to identify all of the stresses and their directions on the cross section.

Comment: i am trying to send you a drawing, but have not figured out how. bear with me. but for my design purpose, i am not interested in the axial/normal stress, I only need the surface friction, the part that is interacting with the surround material, soil or rock.

Comment: You've drawn the FBD with an axial force, and you've shown your shear stresses are perpendicular to one another. I don't see how the shears are in the same plane, one of them looks like a normal stress and the other a radial shear.

Comment: @hazzey any input?

Comment: If your just looking at the skin friction, and not the sectional stresses, then I finally understand. Your looking at the plane of the interface between the lug and the rock? Vector sum :D

Comment: finally, yes, that's exactly what I am asking. ok, so the answer is simple, same as kamran's. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the stresses in this case to are at the same plane, at any given point, so simply by triangle method or vector addition just add them, to verify that you do not surpass the allowable stress.

However keep in mind their projection axially and horizontally for later when you need to calculate Say the torque as opposed to pull out force.

If the stresses where not on the same surface then you could calculate maximum stress and its direction using Mohr circle.

Comment: The torque would resolve into an axial stress that is normal to a cross section surface. How can we neglect interaction of stress?

Comment: torque is orthogonal to axial stress. woul not resolve to axial stress.

Comment: Hi ShadowMan, see my posted sketch, I think it may help. The torque is generating a side friction on the cylinder, or a rotational stress, tangential to the surface, will not generate a axial stress.

Comment: thank you kamran. I think I got it. i can treat them just as two forces, if I am understanding correctly, and the resultant stress would be the maximum stress on the plane in this case.

Comment: @Christian777, yes stress is actually force/ surface unit, but its a vector and will add like vectors. The reason we don't care about the combination of axial and shear stress in beams is they usually maximize in different zones. Like shear at the supports and moment at the middle.

Comment: How is the torque applied ? If the application of the torque causes axial extension then there will be normal stresses.

Comment: It seems.to me that if you torque a bolt in Rock the threads will engage and resist the torque axially. It isn't really clear to me still what the application is but just torque and shear only seems pretty unusual.

Comment: ShadowMan, what is your major/area? I dont know if you hear of a vane shear. that 's the torque applied similar to this. This is a sign structure design. or sometimes a wind turbine. it does have lateral and moment applied at the top, but here, the problem is focused on the substructure, i only want to make sure that the structure does not fail due to the lack of stress in the soil or rock.

Comment: lateral load, moment does matter when talking about the top deflection, but here just a different design focus.

Comment: TBH it isn't clear to me what you are asking, or what your application really is. Your drawing doesn't match your OP and your comments seem to differ as well. There must be a design method that is typically used in your area to check these things. If your just trying to get the magnitude of two orthogonal shears that lie in the same plane, a simple vector sum would do.

Comment: I think you got it now. There's actually not much in my area since torsion is not a typical loading in geotechnical engineering practice.Structure engineering may have a lot more involvement in this, but a typical on-land foundation design has very little related to the torsion simply because typical structure, like a bridge is continuous in one direction and does not exist a torsion loading.